# Spring config - best practise with initialization code

Tags: java, spring

```
@Bean
public Session session(){
    SessionConnector connector=new SessionConnector(url,username,password,environment);
    Session session= connector.getSession();
    session.registerListener(listener());

    return session;
}
@Bean
public Listener listener(){
   return new Listener(session())
}
```

I have the code above which ends up running an endless loop...How can I separate the registration of the listener into a separate method? (I tried creating a temporary private Session bean without the registration code but for some reason you cant have private beans?)

Thxs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Listener` does not have to be a `@Bean`.

You can call a regular `Listener` constructor and pass a session.

Here is modified code:

```
@Bean
public Session session(){
    SessionConnector connector=
      new SessionConnector(url,username,password,environment);
    Session session= connector.getSession();

    // This is modified initialization code
    Listener listener = new Listener( session );
    session.registerListener(listener);

    return session;
}
```

**EDIT**
If you need to have listener as a singleton, then I suggest you register it with the session in its initialization code.

```
@Bean
public Session session(){
    SessionConnector connector=
      new SessionConnector(url,username,password,environment);
    Session session= connector.getSession();

    return session;
}

@Bean
public Listener listener(){
   Session session = session( );
   Listener listener = new Listener( session );

   session.registerListener( listener );

   return listener;
}
```

Comment: I need to reuse listener elsewhere and it needs to be singleton so I need to make it a bean.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use the following pattern just to make sure beans are not instantiated more than once.  You still obviously however need to remove the cyclic dependency.

```
@Bean
public Session session(){
    if (session == null) {
        SessionConnector connector=new SessionConnector(url,username,password,environment);
        session= connector.getSession();
    }
    return session;
}
@Bean
public Listener listener(){
   if (listener == null) {
       Session session = session();
       listener = new Listener(session);
       session.registerListener(listener);
   }
   return listener;
}

private Session session;
private Listener listener;
```